# When exporting to csv special characters (čćšžđ) don't work

Tags: php, excel, csv

Little help need it in export data from database to csv.
My country, unfortunately has special characters čćšžđ.
The export works fine, and if open the .csv in Notepad++ it gives me the correct form of the word. but when it is opened in Excel the special characters are hieroglyphic like.
Example in database i have:
IZLETIŠTE STOJČIĆ in the array before export: IZLETIŠTE STOJČIĆ, in Notepad++ : IZLETIŠTE STOJČIĆ, but in Excel i get IZLETIĹ TE STOJÄŚIÄ†

Why wont it work?
Here is the code, do I have to add something to it or do I need to change something in Excel

```
function convertToCSV($data, $options) {

    $exportName = implode($options['exportName']);

    // setting the csv header
    if (is_array($options) && isset($options['headers']) && is_array($options['headers'])) {
        $headers = $options['headers'];
    } else {
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/csv,charset=UTF-8',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$exportName.'.xls"'
        );
    }

    $output = '';

    // setting the first row of the csv if provided in options array
    if (isset($options['firstRow']) && is_array($options['firstRow'])) {
        $output .= implode('    ', $options['firstRow']);
        $output .= "\n"; // new line after the first line
    }

    // setting the columns for the csv. if columns provided, then fetching the or else object keys
    if (isset($options['columns']) && is_array($options['columns'])) {
        $columns = $options['columns'];
    } else {
        $objectKeys = get_object_vars($data[0]);
        $columns = array_keys($objectKeys);
    }

    // populating the main output string
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $output .= str_replace('    ', ';', $row->$column);
            $output .= '    ';
        }
        $output .= "\n";
    }

    // calling the Response class make function inside my class to send the response.
    // if our class is not a controller, this is required.
    return Response::make($output, 200, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
protected function convertChar($text)
    {
        return @iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-2//TRANSLIT',$text);
    }
```

iconv('UTF-8','**your_code**//TRANSLIT',$text);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a search and replace on `$output` right before returning it. The characters might be percent-encoded so you could try this:

```
$search = array('%C4%8D','%C4%87','%C5%A1','%C5%BE','%C4%91');
$replace = array('č','ć','š','ž','đ');
$output = str_replace($search, $replace, $output);
```

Please let me know if that works.